# Comparing variables to SQL / Troubleshooting session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to send some variables, using a session, to the next page "ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx". As you can see, the sessions have been commented out. The code below will work (without sending the variable of course). However, when you remove the comments the .onclick function reloads the page rather than navigating to "ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx". For this reason, I believe this is where my problem is. The first two columns are "Account" and "Password" in the database. I have not misspelled anything. I am new to VB and ASP.net and would appreciate some explanation as to what is happening and why my desired functionality isn't materializing. Thank you for your help!

```
If IsValid Then
                Try
                    Dim strSQL = "select * from CreatePatient where Account = @Account and Password = @Password"
                        Using CCSQL = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CreatePatientConnectionString").ConnectionString)
                            Using CCUser = New SqlCommand(strSQL, CCSQL)
                                CCSQL.Open()
                                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Account", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PatientAccount.Text
                                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Password", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PatientPass.Text
                                CCUser.ExecuteNonQuery()

                            'Using reader As SqlDataReader = CCUser.ExecuteReader()
                            'If reader.HasRows Then
                            'reader.Read()
                            'Session("user") = reader("Account")
                            'Session("pass") = reader("Password")
                            Response.Redirect("ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx")
                            'End If
                            'End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Label1.Text = ex.Message
                End Try
            End If
```

Comment: Aside from the sql correction noted below, `when you remove the comments the .onclick function reloads the page rather than navigating to "ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx"` - Have you debugged your code to verify if it actually gets to that section - re: `IsValid` on `Postback`? You can [step through debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) so you know more about why things don't work..Hth.

Comment: Yes. Leaving the lines commented works and navigates to "ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx". I believe my problem is trying to read from the database. The connection to the database is open. Thank you for the link, i will use it as a reference

Answer (score 1):

My friend was able to make time to help me out. I am unsure of what he did differently besides closing connections

```
If IsValid Then
            Dim CCSQL As New SqlConnection
            Dim CCUser As New SqlCommand
            Dim strSQL As String
            Dim dtrUser As SqlDataReader
            Try
                CCSQL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CreatePatientConnectionString").ConnectionString
                strSQL = "Select * from CreatePatient where Account=@user and Password=@pwd"
                CCUser.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                CCUser.CommandText = strSQL
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@user", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PatientAccount.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@pwd", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PatientPass.Text

                CCSQL.Open()
                CCUser.Connection = CCSQL
                dtrUser = CCUser.ExecuteReader()
                If dtrUser.HasRows Then
                    dtrUser.Read()
                    Session("user") = dtrUser("Account")
                    Session("level") = dtrUser("Password")


                    Response.Redirect("ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx")

                Else
                    Label1.Text = "Please check your user name and password"

                End If
                dtrUser.Close()
                CCSQL.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Label1.Text = ex.Message
            End Try
        End If
```

I am on a tight deadline but i will get back to those interested with an answer. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to do `.ExecuteNonQuery()` when you are actually doing a query (i.e. a SQL "`SELECT`" statement. You can just do the `.ExecuteReader()` to read those two values.
Also, I presume you are trying to validate the Account and Password; otherwise you could just set `Session("user") = PatientAccount.Text` and set `Session("pass") = PatientPass.Text`.

Comment: thank you, i made the changes you suggested. it did not fix my problem but efficient code is always welcome